# Can't extend volume

Tags: partitioning, windows-server-2003, mbr

Found unused 90GB on array on Windows 2003 Server SP2 and extended array into it. In Disk Manager it is now shown as unallocated of MBR type and no option to extend existing volumes into it. Diskpart can't do it neither. Only option active is to create a new partition.
Any possibility to add it to the existing ones?

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]

Comment: I do not a have windows 2003 here to test, but it looks as if you had this:   [Primary partition] [extended parttion with a 125GB volume in it] [empty space]?  In which case you cannot expand the volume in the extended partition without expanding the externded partition first. Which means clicking on that and not on the volume.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that partition E: is not a primary partition. Instead, it is a logical volume contained in an Extended Partition. To increase its size, you need to increase its container’s, the Extended Partition’s, size. This is not possible using Windows-integrated tools. Instead, you’ll have to use a third-party partition manager like [GPartEd](http://gparted.org/) or [AOMEI Partition Assistant](http://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html).

However, now that you decided to convert your disk to Microsoft’s proprietary Dynamic Disk scheme, you’re out of luck. This change is not easily reversible. Depending on how exactly the partitions are set up now, there may still be a chance. AOMEI offers a [dedicated tool](http://www.disk-partition.com/AOMEI-ddc.html) for that. I haven’t tried this tool yet. It is also **not free of charge**. I am not aware of free tools for that.

Dynamic Disks are fully usable *only* with Windows. Most cheaper backup/rescue tools will refuse to access them. So it’s not a good idea to use them, unless you want their Software RAID capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

DiskManager offer very limited functionality and it might not let you extend the new partition.
If it does let you - it's only to an adjacent one.
You could try other commercial or free products with better functionality.
I use MiniTool Partition Wizard free edition which offer a simple GUI to most of partition management functionality.
You can get it the free addition [here](http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html).
[How to](http://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmagic/ssd-partition-resizing.html) Resize SSD Partition with MiniTool Partition Wizard

Comment: Disk Manager has pretty advanced functionality and lets you extend and shrink partitions live. The problem is he has an extended partition.

Comment: I would be totaly fine with extending the adjacent partition E, but I don't have this option: <img src='http://s12.postimg.org/3rlwu3gzx/diskmanager1.png'>

Comment: @Astralex: That's because you have an extended partition.

Comment: (AKA Logical partition)

Answer (score 0):

From that screenshot, I can't see any reason the Main (E:) can't be right-clicked and extended into the empty space adjacent to it.

OP did use the word "array" in the question.  If there is a RAID going, extending isn't going to happen.  For one, Windows *software* won't be able to do much with a *hardware* RAID.  Second, if the drives aren't the same size in the array, the smallest would be the limiting factor for total capacity.

Find out if there's a hardware RAID and whether or not it's worth backing up and restoring the system for the possibility of another 67 GB.

Comment: I can't see any reason neither, but there is no such option in the right click menu as you can see: <a href='http://postimage.org/' target='_blank'><img src='http://s12.postimg.org/3rlwu3gzx/diskmanager1.png' border='0' alt="diskmanager1" /></a>
Yes, the drives are on RAID5 array, but the array extention did work without any problems and gave me that unallocated partition I'm trying to use.

Comment: As long as windows sees the array as a single drive then there should be no difference between in functionality between a real single drive and a fake single drive build up from an array of disks. The RAID card hides that difference.

Comment: @Hennes - Indeed it does.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that the disc was of type Basic. Converted it to Dynamic and could extend it then.

Comment: Well, now you’re SOL. This is *not* the issue.

Comment: @DanielB I find it hard to understand your comment. The OP has solved his/her own problem. How can you possibly suggest that they do not understand the issue?

Comment: @DanielB The OP has solved his/her own problem in a way that they are happy with, even if not ideal or best practice. Can you explain why they should not have used this approach more clearly (noting that the OP appears to not be a native English speaker, given the screenshots).

Comment: @AdamV Take a look at my answer. Also, I did not downvote.