# Windows 10 - Is there a way to Expand System Partition Size?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-10, ssd

When I bought the computer the partitioning was already done by the vendor. However they gave it an incredibly little amount (about 50GB). Many apps mandatorily occupy space at system drive, especially Visual Studio, which quickly left me short on space. In "Disk Manager" the option to expand this partition is grayed out even though I have spare space on the same SSD. Is there any way out of it? Or is the only way to deal with it a complete reinstallation(which I really don't want)? I have also installed Ubuntu as dualboot. Would I be able to resize the partition in Ubuntu, for example?

The information shown by disk management is:

[image]

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of your Disk management? edit: thanks

Comment: @kush Was just doing this. Now here it is.

Comment: Have you tried 'diskpart' from command line?

Comment: What partition are you trying to extend exactly.  **The only "free space" you have is in a logical extended volume.** So the only partition you can extend is the `Windows Apps` partition.  [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/1008498/cant-extend-volume/1008529#comment1397332_1008529) is a question with a explaination

Comment: You also have a couple partitions between your system volume and the partition with `free space` so those partitions would have to be deleted if you wanted to extend the primary system partition.

Comment: You can only expand the partition into space that is free and contiguous (right next to).  Per your screenshot there is no free space that is contiguous.  You might be able to shuffle things around.  Whatever you do, make a full backup a first.

Comment: Under your condition, the disk manager built into Windows isn't able to perform its operations, recmmend you expand partition using Easeus partition master. Make a full image backup of your hard drive before you start.

Answer (score 1):

Disk Management tool windows cant allocate partition **before drive** it can free partition **only after drive** so you cant extend partition by disk management without deleting partitions but this solutions software helps to extend without format and more convenient

To extend partition there must be free unallocated space just next or before to it.You have free unallocated space next to E(Windows Apps)but not near C

To extend C drive partition you have to do simple steps

Its better to use a software named Ease US partition master for you to do safely and easy

1.Open EaseUS partition manager and select the drive you want to shrink(D) and click resize

[image]

2.Since you want to increase size of partition before it C increase the "Unallocated before" to your specified size by sliding the 1st end and click on Ok

[image]

3.Then click on execute operation at top after that a reboot may be required

[image]

4.After un-allocated partition has been done select C drive then click on Resize and move then extend partition as shown then select Ok and execute operation as shown in step-3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was likely that Windows was installed in a primary partition while that free space I had was within an extended partition (which contains Ubuntu in a logical partition), and thus they couldn't be merged. To do so I had to first convert the logical partition to primary partition, which is a bit complicated. In the end I just chose to delete the whole extended partition, expand the system drive and reinstall Ubuntu on the new primary partition created based on space that was left.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the volume ( add more free space to it) it is necessary to have free "unallocated space" (this would be color coded black). To make free unallocated space you'd need to delete a drive and that'd make it's space of the type: unallocated. After this you'd be able to extend a volume on the same disk with that free unallocated space.

You could also diminish a volume and thus freeing up space that would become unallocated and therefore a candidate for extending another volume on the same disk.